# How do you set an 'active' class in React and CSS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have navigation in my React app. However I would like the colour of navigation to change if on that page.

Heres my code Ive added an active className to the items.

```
        <Link to='/'>
          <li className='menu-list-item menu-list-logo   active'>Gatsby's</li>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/drink'>
          <li className='menu-list-item active'>Drink</li>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/food'>
          <li className='menu-list-item active'>Food</li>
        </Link>
        <Link to='contact'>
          <li className='menu-list-item active'>Contact</li>
        </Link>
```

The navigation links currently have a background of black. I want the colour to change to lets say red.
P.S I'm using standard CSS for styles.

Comment: If your using react router which i assume you are just use `<NavLink>` instead of `<Link>` and it will add the active class for you https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a property of activeClassName in `NavLink` of react router.

It goes like this

```
Import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom`
...

<NavLink exact activeClassName="your_active_css_classname" className="normal_css">Link name </NavLink>
```

Don't forget to add exact. Read more here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Answer (score 0):

Light/Fast way to do this would be to change the class at the parent DOM element of these `<Link>` elements... from there the CSS would do what it works best.

Assuming these `<Link> ... </Link>` tags are enclosed inside a `<nav> ... </nav>` tag, which is the parent DOM element.

```
{ (onThePage) ? <nav className="onThePageClass"> ... </nav> : <nav className="normalClass"> ... </nav> }
```

Try this else share MVCE if you get stuck so that it serves as a good example for others looking for help